# Use Pandoc to create YAML Metadata from HTML META Tags

Tags: html, metadata, yaml, markdown, pandoc

I have a batch of HTML files. Each has its own title and description in the standard HTML meta tags. I'd like to convert them all to Markdown, but I'd like to retain that metadata, in the form of a YAML metadata header, at the top of the resulting markdown files. Is it possible to do this with Pandoc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, pandoc will do this, but only if you use version 1.12.3 or later.

```
pandoc -f html -t markdown -s input.html -o output.md
```

Comment: That worked for me, thank you. It didn't work with markdown_github or markdown_strict but that's ok for my purposes.